# Filter a CSV file by time columns

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have the csv file with the following structure. It has 5 columns.

```
2/3/2018    17:00:00    39.50755167 139.94117   72
.....
2/1/2018    1:00:00     37.67323333 140.0666667 48
......
```

I want to filter the csv file and select all the data rows that happened before the 2/3/2018 17:00:00 and save the filtered data into a new csv file.

Comment: There’s not a whole lot of C’s in that CSV. Are the fields delimited by tabs or spaces?

Comment: the csv is delimited by a comma. It should be 2/3/2018 17:00:00, 39.50755167, 139.94117, 72

Comment: there is no comma between the date and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your dates are MM/DD/YYYY (and not DD/MM/YYYY).
I assume that you want the cutoff to be externally specified (hard coded) and not based on the first line.

You can do it in gawk (GNU awk):

```
awk '
  BEGIN { cutoff = mktime("2018 2 3 17 0 0");
          if (cutoff < 0) { print "Bad cutoff date."; exit; } }
        {
            if (split($1, da, "/") == 3  &&  split($2, ti, ":") == 3) {
                thisdate = mktime(da[3] " " da[1] " " da[2] " " ti[1] " " ti[2] " " ti[3])
                if (thisdate >= 0  &&  thisdate < cutoff) print
            }
        }
    '
```

The gawk’s `mktime` function converts a time string in the form “YYYY MM DD hh mm ss” to a system time.
We start (BEGIN) by converting 2/3/2018 17:00:00 to a system time.
Then, for each line, we verify that it contains a valid date and time, convert it, and compare it to the cutoff.

Of course, if your file is really comma-separated, you should use `-F,`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Instead of printing the results, how can I save the filtered data into a new csv file? Thanks

Comment: Actually, I got to know your code. I don't need to pass the values to the da and ti variables. I saved your code to a test.awk file. I run the following code : awk -f test.awk data.csv
But it didn't print anything. Do you have any tips?